# Comparing frequencies in stationary distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes

Do there exist theorems for comparing frequencies in the stationary distribution of a (say) aperiodic, positive recurrent Markov chain? i.e. given the transition probability matrix $\mathbf{P}$ with stationary distribution $\boldsymbol{\pi}$, and given two states of interest, $i$ and $j$, are there properties of $\mathbf{P}$ that might imply that $\pi_i > \pi_j$? (Other than just $P_{ki} > P_{kj}$ for all $k$, of course!)